# Templates and Shared Libraries in D

Tags: templates, shared-libraries, d

I *just* realized something:

Nearly everything in D is becoming templated. That' *awesome* for a single executable, but how does that *work* with shared libraries? If no code is generated until it's compiled, then D can't make shared libraries that use templates, can it? (e.g. Phobos *has* to be static -- there's no other way, right?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's the same issue like with C++ code.

Only the non-templated parts can be precompiled. Everything else must be provided with full source code.

Phobos being a shared or static library doesn't make much difference here. It's still static because of dmd's issues with shared libraries.

Comment: It might also be a DMD issue, but how can Phobos be possibly shared, even if DMD didn't have a problem?

Comment: Of course it can be shared. It's just that the portion which is templated isn't shared. It's the same reason why templates have to be in the header file in C++. It's the exact same issue with the exact same reasons. So, D can have shared libraries just as easily as C++ as far as templates go. The problems with shared libraries in D come from issues with the compiler and the garbage collector, and those will eventually be resolved. So, in the end, it's pretty much exactly the same situation as C++.

Comment: The only major difference would be the fact that templates are more heavily used in D (particularly in Phobos) making less code truly shareable. But overall, the situation is the same as with C++.

Comment: IMHO, for many cases (but not all, e.g. system libaries), dynamic libraries are just not worth the hassle. Unless you *know* that some part will be updated by someone who can't rebuild the whole things, just use static linkage for everything you can. :b

Comment: @BCS: It depends on the library. I usually don't like them either, but when a static library gets into the megabyte range and you're linking it with a lot of programs, it may be wise to share it instead.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That might be a good rule of thumb. OTOH I'd put the critical point closer to say 200MB (That's something like an order of magnitude smaller than a "smallish" memory desktop PC and 3 smaller than a "small" HDD) and a few dozen copies of the code. And IIRC, many installer install their own copy of libs anyway rather than trusting what's their to work.

Comment: @BCS: 200 MB?!! I freak out when I have a 1 MB binary that I can trim down to 300 KB (e.g. by linking with `msvcrt.dll` instead of some other random CRT)... it even speeds up the loading. 200 MB is a bit beyond my imagination, sorry. D:

Comment: @Mehrdad: IIRC all common OS's use memory paging to load code sections so what really counts is how much code you use, not how much you link in. Using DLL/so's might even slow things down as it drags in mapping multiple files, dynamic fix-ups, etc. And BTW, I'd consider msvcrt.dll to be a system liberality and thus excepted. The bits I'm thinking of are the ones that (if you leave them dynamic) will end up in the installer anyway because you can't assume the user (i.e OS) will have already installed them.

Comment: @BCS: True, I was mainly thinking of msvcrt.dll. msvcr90.dll is the exact opposite of that, actually... it's worse than static linking. :)

Comment: Shared libraries are not only useful for smaller binary sizes. You can't do plugins without them. And for plugins to work well, all libraries used by the plugin and the host application should also be shared libraries.